# Angular service returning object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

As far as I understand Angularjs services are created by passing in a Contructor function:

```
app.service('serviceName', function(){
  this.var1 = 'foo';

  this.method1 =  function(){

   }
});
```

Angular runs this function with the **new** operator.

I was going through this service, and i don't see any "this" insider

```
https://github.com/shreya5/angular-facebook-utils/blob/master/src/scripts/facebookUser.js
```

Infact this function returns  **deferred.promise**

Can someone shed some light on what's going on here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to choose whatever pattern you want. Just because angular runs your function with `new` doesn't obligate you to use `this` nor does it require you to return the default object.

For example, this is a pretty nice idiom that I use in Angular services a lot:

```
function myConstructor(me){  
    me = me || "Mark";
    return {
        name: me,
        sayit: function(){return "Say my name, " + me}
     };

 }
 var obj = new myConstructor("Steve");
 console.log(obj.sayit())
 console.log(obj.name)
```

Comment: As a formal parameter, `me` does not need to be redeclared with `var`. `me =  me || "Mark";` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned from service depends on how it will be used. You are free to return whatever you want. From [another file](https://github.com/shreya5/angular-facebook-utils/blob/master/src/scripts/app.js) where this `facebookUser` will be used, it's used as a promise, `facebookUser.then`.

```
facebookUser.then(function(user) {
    if (!user.loggedIn) {
       // reload the login route
       $location.path(facebookConfigSettings.loginPath || facebookConfigDefaults.loginPath);
    }
});
```